# Cannot destroy active lambda function

Tags: php, lambda, closures

Can someone tell me the most common reasons to see this error in PHP:

> Cannot destroy active lambda function in...

I'm guessing that somewhere there is code that's trying to destroy a closure that contains a reference to itself and the compiler is annoyed at this.

We get these more regularly than I'd like and I'm wondering what pattern we are using that's the likely culprit that's causing it.

I would attach a code snippet but the error typically points to a file not to a line in a file that might provide a hint.

Answer (score 1):

There is similar bug posted in php.net regarding the same.  Below is the link .

Hope it will be helpful to you.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62452

Answer (score 1):

Such a fatal error will result in code like this:

```
set_exception_handler(function ($e) {
        echo "My exception handler";

        restore_exception_handler();

        throw new Exception("Throw this instead.");
});
throw new Exception("An exception");
```

Or like this:

```
function destroy_handler() {
    restore_exception_handler();
}

function update_handler() {
    destroy_handler();
}

set_exception_handler(function ($e) {
        echo "My exception handler";

        update_handler();

        throw new Exception("Throw this instead.");
});
throw new Exception("An exception");
```

When an exception is thrown the callback given to `set_exception_handler()` is executed and as soon as the `restore_exception_handler()` is called, the fatal error occurs because the same reference to that closure is being destroyed (or reassigned) inside its own scope (the same goes in the example of `hanskrentel at yahoo dot de` in the link posted by `Sameer K`).

You can see from the second example that, even with nested scopes, the same occurs. This is because `restore_exception_handler` will destroy the last set exception handler, and not a copy of it (it's like re-assigning a variable or unset it while you are still evaluating the expression that will give the variable an initial value).

If you say that the error in your code points to another file, I suggest you to check all the calls in your lambda which execution "jumps" in functions and or methods in other files and check there if you are reassigning or destroying a reference to the lambda itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `set_exception_handler` will return the previous exception handler:

> Returns the name of the previously defined exception handler, or NULL on error. If no previous handler was defined, NULL is also returned.
>   [php.net: set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

```
<?php

class MyException extends Exception {}

set_exception_handler(function(Exception $e){
    echo "Old handler:".$e->getMessage();
});

$lastHandler = set_exception_handler(function(Exception $e) use (&$lastHandler) {
    if ($e instanceof MyException) {
        echo "New handler:".$e->getMessage();
        return;
    }

    if (is_callable($lastHandler)) {
        return call_user_func_array($lastHandler, [$e]);
    }

    throw $e;
});
```

Trigger the exception handler:

```
throw new MyException("Exception one", 1);
```

Output: `New handler:Exception one`

```
throw new Exception("Exception two", 1);
```

Output: `Old handler:Exception two`